# full width for an input-append element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have a div `row` with an `input-append` (a field with two buttons on the right) that spans all the width of the row itself. In other words, I would like to have this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="input-append">
          <input class="" id="appendedInputButtons" type="text">
          <button class="btn" type="button">Search</button>
          <button class="btn" type="button">Options</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with `<div class="input-append">` that takes all the width available (span 12 of its parent).

To be more pragmatic, I would like to transform this code in order to have my input element to cover all the available space the row has: http://jsfiddle.net/bertuz/tS6Dm/

If I set the class `span12` to my `input` element, the two buttons overflow of course. And that's not what I want. Any piece of suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

what if you add some span class to all three elements? something like that

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="controls controls-row">
        <input class="span8" type="text" placeholder="Text input">
        <button class="btn span2" type="button">Search</button>
        <button class="btn span2" type="button">Options</button>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

by the way, your jsfiddle don't work because the bootstrap css is not included ;)

Comment: Humm, that's not exactly a solution for having an input-append effect with a full width, BUT it is a very good alternative to that! Thanks

Comment: you're welcome :) I'm curious to see another answers, idk if there is a better way to do it, using the grid system and being able to be responsive

Comment: responsive you say? You really want too much ;)
The only problem with this solutions is that the button seldom fits what it wraps, therefore you have larger buttons most of the times.

Comment: Agreed ;) but it's the cost of the grid system :( You can do it using jQuery though, by setting the input width depending on the div width, and calculating it on the document resize/ready events